# How to create a plug-in for openoffice on mac

Tags: macos, openoffice.org

hi am planing to create a small plug-in for OpenOffice on mac lion. Can some one let me know how to initiate the process As am unable to find any route in starting this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should read: http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development

Assuming you want to make it using Java, I recommand you to:

- Install OpenOffice.org
- Install OpenOffice.org SDK
- Install Netbeans
- Install Netbeans OpenOffice.org Extension
  (http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_NetBeans_Integration)

You will have stubs for creating OpenOffice.org extensions in Netbeans > New Project